# Apply Multiple filter in odoo at a time

Tags: javascript, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

Currently I am using odoov8, my problem is that I have created many filters from xml code as per my requirement and all are working fine ,but I can select only one filter at a time .

so for example I want to apply any 3 Filters in tree view , then I need to select first one , then system loads the data , then I select 2nd and then 3rd filter , so system is loading after applying each filter .

I want to achieve that if I can select all my filters at once and then I can apply search , so system loads after I apply for search , no matter how much time it taking but I should not require to search single filter .

so is there any custom module or way from which I can achieve this .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can make custom filters and set it as a default

Comment: But it will not be flexible , I want to achieve that user should able to select the filters that he wanted to apply at a time .

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any module that implements this.

This functionality already exists on the `Advanced Search`, you add conditions and then click `Apply` you can take a look at the corresponding widget and copy functionality.

What you need to do is modify the javascript so that upon the clicking of a filter it should be added on the `oe_searchview` view but the `search_read` method will not be invoked. You need to start the modifications from `web.search.FilterGroup` widget and specifically from the `search_change` method which is invoked every time you click on the filters.